# Is the Social Security with disability option final?

Tags: united-states, social-security

My dad is planning on retiring and collecting Social Security, he just had quad bypass surgery. It looks like he has the option to take Social Security by invoking disability.

These are his options:

Wait 2 more years and get his full social security
Take SS without disability now which is pretty low.
Or take SS now with disability and get about $50 less than his full SS in 2 years.

What he doesn't want to do is take SS with disability now and later have the disability "wear off" and then be forced to the normal SS he would get if he collects early.

So does anyone know if you take SS with disability is that set in stone as the SS payment or can it then be scaled back.

Comment: These are two different benefits. Early retirement benefit and disability benefit are distinct.

Comment: So you are asking whether he should do one of three different things? Is that correct? If so, could you edit the question accordingly? I see @littleadv comment, and in light of that, do not understand what you are asking exactly. If you take early retirement, you can return to work, stop getting benefits, work until after regular retirement age, and later, retire with full benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out Social Security and disability insurance are two different things but if you take disability insurance before retirement age when you get to full retirement age the disability money becomes the social security money. http://www.ssa.gov/dibplan/dqualify.htm

> If you are receiving Social Security disability benefits when you reach full retirement age, your disability benefits automatically convert to retirement benefits, but the amount remains the same.